# Odd Emacs behavior OSX 10.9.2 (Mavericks)

Tags: emacs, terminal, osx-mavericks

Emacs randomly started doing strange things on my mac -- I'm not sure exactly when it started; it could have been when I updated to Mavericks in the fall. Basically, it randomly doesn't allow me to edit certain lines of text, or it will display files incorrectly (i.e. it deletes some characters).

For example:
I just typed a .txt file containing "hihihi". Upon saving and then reopening the file in emacs, it only displayed "ihihi". This is a simple example...sometimes it deletes whole lines; regardless, this is extraordinarily annoying. However, I do know that it's not actually altering the file, because if I open the same file in Vim it still displays the original content. Emacs is just displaying the files incorrectly.

Has anyone experienced something similar and found a solution?

I've been trying to just install a newer version of emacs, but I think that I'm still running the old version, not the newer version that I installed with homebrew. If anyone has any suggestions for how to fix that I would also appreciate it!

Thanks!

Comment: I run emacs in server mode in Mavericks. I have this in my `.bash_profile`. `alias emacs='/usr/local/Cellar/emacs/24.3/bin/emacsclient --alternate-editor="" -c $@'`. This allows me to do `emacs -n` and will automatically start the Emacs server if it is not running, then open a new frame. (You may need to adjust some paths if you do not use the defaults)

Comment: So basically you're saying I could do something similar to ensure that I'm running the newer version of emacs that I just installed?

Comment: You could also `brew link emacs`, and as long as `/usr/local/bin` comes before `/usr/bin` in your `PATH`, you should be fine. Just do `emacs --version` to find out what version of emacs is being loaded.

Comment: Ok cool -- this might be a stupid question, but how do I ensure that /usr/local/bin is before usr/bin in my path?

Comment: in your `.bash_profile`, you can have something like `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:$PATH`. This will ensure that `/usr/local/bin` comes before `/usr/bin`, which *should* takes the homebrew installs before system installs.